# Picture Library Slideshow Webpart Library View

Tags: web-part, list-view, view, picture-library

I inherited a SharePoint site that has a photo gallery section. Inside the photo gallery there are multiple pages and each page is supposed to have a filtered list of photos in the slideshow from the picture library. The picture library contains several thousand photos placed directly in the library without folders. Under the library settings, I see there are Views setup for each category and each slideshow has one of the views setup under the picture library webpart:

[image]

[image]

However, when you view each slideshow page, it is displaying all pictures from the entire picture library instead of what is assigned to "Memorial Day 2014" as pictured above. I was told there was a drop down when you edit a picture's properties to assign the picture to a category, but I do not see that option.

How can pictures be categorized into separate groups and then be displayed in a picture library slideshow webpart so only the pictures assigned to the categories are displayed... instead of everything in the library?